# Cabal install gtk failing

Tags: haskell, gtk, cabal, c2hs

I'm trying to install gtk via cabal, however, I'm getting the following type errors when building it

```
[ 22 of 209] Compiling Graphics.UI.Gtk.Embedding.Plug ( dist/build/Graphics/UI/Gtk/Embedding/Plug.hs, dist/build/Graphics/UI/Gtk/Embedding/Plug.o )

Graphics/UI/Gtk/Embedding/Plug.chs:120:6: error:
    Couldn't match expected type ‘Ptr ()’
                with actual type ‘Maybe DrawWindow’
    In the first argument of ‘gtk_plug_new’, namely
      ‘(fromNativeWindowId (fromMaybe nativeWindowIdNone socketId))’
    In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely
      ‘gtk_plug_new
         (fromNativeWindowId (fromMaybe nativeWindowIdNone socketId))’

Graphics/UI/Gtk/Embedding/Plug.chs:137:6: error:
    Couldn't match expected type ‘Ptr ()’
                with actual type ‘Maybe DrawWindow’
    In the second argument of ‘\ (Display arg1) arg2
                                 -> withForeignPtr arg1
                                    $ \ argPtr1 -> gtk_plug_new_for_display argPtr1 arg2’, namely
      ‘(fromNativeWindowId (fromMaybe nativeWindowIdNone socketId))’
    In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely
      ‘(\ (Display arg1) arg2
          -> withForeignPtr arg1
             $ \ argPtr1 -> gtk_plug_new_for_display argPtr1 arg2)
         display
         (fromNativeWindowId (fromMaybe nativeWindowIdNone socketId))’

Graphics/UI/Gtk/Embedding/Plug.chs:151:3: error:
    Couldn't match type ‘Ptr ()’ with ‘Maybe DrawWindow’
    Expected type: IO (Maybe DrawWindow)
      Actual type: IO (Ptr ())
    In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely
      ‘(\ (Plug arg1)
          -> withForeignPtr arg1 $ \ argPtr1 -> gtk_plug_get_id argPtr1)
         (toPlug self)’
    In the expression:
      liftM toNativeWindowId
      $ (\ (Plug arg1)
           -> withForeignPtr arg1 $ \ argPtr1 -> gtk_plug_get_id argPtr1)
          (toPlug self)
Failed to install gtk-0.13.9
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
gtk-0.13.9 failed during the building phase. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
```

To install this package, you need "gtk2hsC2hs" and the type errors are in `.chs` files, which presumably are generated from the gtk2hsC2hs tool.  Is this a known problem with gtk2hsC2hs?  Has anyone else been able to build this package?  Anyone know of a solution?

I'm on Mac OS X Yosemite (10.10.4)

```sh
$ gtk2hsC2hs --version
C->Haskell Compiler, version 0.13.13 (gtk2hs branch) "Bin IO", 27 May 2012

$ cabal --version
cabal-install version 1.22.6.0
using version 1.22.4.0 of the Cabal library
```

I've done a `cabal update`, so all my packages appear to be up to date.  I've also tried building some of the older versions available from hackage, but I'm getting the same errors.

**Edit**

The errors in the generated files, seem to all deal with the FFI imports that are getting generated by gtk2hsC2hs.  At the bottom of the file, I'm getting

```
foreign import ccall unsafe "gtk_plug_new"
  gtk_plug_new :: ((Ptr ()) -> (IO (Ptr Widget)))
```

It seems to consistently mix up `Ptr()` with `Maybe DrawWindow`.
So is the generated type `Ptr()` incorrect, or is the usage of it incorrect?

Comment: Just a quick comment, haven't had time to look enough to write an answer: `.chs` files are not generated by `gtk2hsC2hs`; they are written by hand, and processed by `gtk2hsC2hs` to produce `.hs` files. If you want, you can look in those files; `cabal` stores them in the `dist` directory. There will be pragmas pointing back from the `.hs` file to the `.chs` file, which is how GHC knows where in the `.chs` file to point in its errors.

Comment: Ok thanks for the tip. I'll look into that.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This had a really simple solution.

```
cabal install gtk -fhave-quartz-gtk
```

It would be nice if this was more well documented, but hopefully this will help anyone else that ends up in a similar situation

Comment: Just helped me. I can confirm that it works on MacOSX 10.8. Thanks! :)

Comment: Stack variant (e.g., for installing threadscope): `stack install --flag gtk:have-quartz-gtk threadscope`

Comment: Neither of these workarounds help on catalina in 2021 :/