# cabal-dev: command not found

Tags: haskell, cabal-dev

Whenever I'm running any command that includes **cabal-dev**, I'm getting the following error:
**cabal-dev: command not found**
I've downloaded cabal-dev package from
http://hackage.haskell.org/package/cabal-dev
But there are no instructions on how to install it.

Comment: `cabal-dev` is deprecated. Use `cabal-install` instead of that. (Or Stack which provides a better UX in my opinion.).

Comment: *cabal-dev* is a predecessor to the [`cabal sandbox` command of *cabal-install*](https://www.haskell.org/cabal/users-guide/installing-packages.html#developing-with-sandboxes), so any usage instructions involving one should translate to the other in a reasonably direct way.

Comment: As mentioned in the following website,   
https://wiki.haskell.org/Cabal/How_to_install_a_Cabal_package  
when I'm trying to run the command,     
**runhaskell Setup configure**  
I'm getting the errors  
**Setup: Encountered missing dependencies:  
Cabal >=1.2 && <1.17, process >=1.0 && <1.2**

OR

**Setup: Encountered missing dependencies:  
utf8-string >=0.2 && <1.1**

@Sibi

Comment: Using `Setup.{l,}hs` directly hasn't been typical for a long time.  Download and install `cabal-install` then install Haskell packages using `cabal install <package name>`.

Comment: I'm getting errors when I'm trying to run **cabal install <package name>** command. That's the sole reason I'm trying to install packages manually and whenever I'm trying to do this I'm always getting the error **Setup: Encountered missing dependencies:**
Any idea on how to correct it?
@ThomasM.DuBuisson

Comment: You should make a new question with your full command and output.  Starting from `cabal --version` to `cabal install <foo package>` then maybe `cabal install <foo package> -v3`.

Comment: It has been done at
`http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43331920/installing-cabal-packages-returns-errors`
@ThomasM.DuBuisson

Comment: The output of `cabal install <foo package> -v3` hasn't been added since it's very huge.
@ThomasM.DuBuisson

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has something to do with MacOS. This command solved the problem.

```
cabal install gtk -fhave-quartz-gtk
```

Source : https://stackoverflow.com/a/32053264/5524175